# Парсинг на Python

Tags: python

Есть список

```
['ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ "ТЮМЕНЬ ВОДОКАНАЛ"', 'ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ 
 ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ "КОМПАНИЯ СОТНЯ"', 'ГОСУДАРСТВЕННОЕ АВТОНОМНОЕ УЧРЕЖДЕНИЕ ЗДРАВООХРАНЕНИЯ 
 ТЮМЕНСКОЙ ОБЛАСТИ "ДЕТСКИЙ ЛЕЧЕБНО-РЕАБИЛИТАЦИОННЫЙ ЦЕНТР "НАДЕЖДА"', 'ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ 
 ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ "ЖЕЛЕЗНАЯ-МЕБЕЛЬ"', 'Индивидуальный предприниматель Баландина Валентина 
 Васильевна']
```

я хочу получить список

```
['ООО "ТЮМЕНЬ ВОДОКАНАЛ"', 'ООО "КОМПАНИЯ СОТНЯ"', 'ГАУЗ 
 ТЮМЕНСКОЙ ОБЛАСТИ "ДЕТСКИЙ ЛЕЧЕБНО-РЕАБИЛИТАЦИОННЫЙ ЦЕНТР "НАДЕЖДА"', 'ООО "ЖЕЛЕЗНАЯ- 
 МЕБЕЛЬ"', 'ИП Баландина Валентина Васильевна']
```

Подскажите как мне такой список получить?

Comment: string.replace(oldStr, newStr, count), составить массив из объектов со свойствами old и new и сделать перебор вложенный с методом replace

Comment: а что такое oldStr, newStr, count?

Answer (score 0):

Ну какой тут парсинг... Банальная замена

```
data = ['ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ "ТЮМЕНЬ ВОДОКАНАЛ"', 'ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ "КОМПАНИЯ СОТНЯ"', 'ГОСУДАРСТВЕННОЕ АВТОНОМНОЕ УЧРЕЖДЕНИЕ ЗДРАВООХРАНЕНИЯ ТЮМЕНСКОЙ ОБЛАСТИ "ДЕТСКИЙ ЛЕЧЕБНО-РЕАБИЛИТАЦИОННЫЙ ЦЕНТР "НАДЕЖДА"', 'ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ "ЖЕЛЕЗНАЯ-МЕБЕЛЬ"', 'Индивидуальный предприниматель Баландина Валентина Васильевна']

for idx in range(len(data)):
    data[idx] = data[idx].replace("ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ", "ООО")
    data[idx] = data[idx].replace("ГОСУДАРСТВЕННОЕ АВТОНОМНОЕ УЧРЕЖДЕНИЕ ЗДРАВООХРАНЕНИЯ", "ГАУЗ")
    data[idx] = data[idx].replace("Индивидуальный предприниматель", "ИП")
```